# Sidemenus in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my file in angularjs. I am not able to insert the code for sidemenus. If I include that code, the style of ion-nav-view changes and the page is blank. Pls help me to get to know the exact place I should insert the menu.

```
   <ion-nav-view class="dashboard_pane">

        <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">

            <button menu-toggle = "left" class = "button button-icon icon ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleSideMenu()"></button>
            <h1 class="title">DASHBOARD</h1>
            <button class="button" ng-click="getSyncData()" style='background-image:url(../img/sync.png);width:35px;height:35px;background-size:cover'></button>

        </ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content padding="true" >


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-60 col-offset-60" style='background-image:url(../img/schbg1.png);width:15px;height:160px;background-size: 100% 100%;'><img ng-src='../img/about.png' ng-click="AboutUs()"/></div>
                    <div class="col col-60 col-offset-60" style='background-image:url(../img/schbg1.png);width:15px;height:160px;background-size:100% 100%'><img ng-src='../img/contact.png' ng-click="ContactUs()" /></div>
                </div>

</ion-content>
   </ion-nav-view>
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-light" style='background-image:url(../img/advertisement_button.png);background-size:cover;width:100%;height:8%;'></div>
        </body>
```

---

Is the header section fine ?

```
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
            <button menu-toggle = "left" class = "button button-icon icon ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleSideMenu()"></button>
            <h1 class="title">DASHBOARD</h1>
            <button class="button" ng-click="getSyncData()" style='background-image:url(../img/sync.png);width:35px;height:35px;background-size:cover'></button>
    </ion-header-bar>

  </ion-nav-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create side menus in ionic, you have to use `<ion-side-menus>` directive as parent directive. Inside that you have use 2 directive (3 directives if you are using both right and left menu): 
**One for main body content** `<ion-side-menu-content>` Main body or `<ion-nav-view>` will go here. **Another for left/right menu** : `<ion-side-menu side="left">` 
Example Code:

```
 <ion-side-menus>
     <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive header-color">
        <!-- Header title and back button codes-->
      </ion-nav-bar>

      <ion-nav-view animation="slide-ios">
        <!-- Main body content will go here -->
      </ion-nav-view>

    </ion-side-menu-content> 

    <ion-side-menu side="left" enable-menu-with-back-views="false" width="290">
      <ion-content has-header="false">

        <!-- Left menu code will go here-->
        <!-- You can also create a separate html file for left menu and include like this -->
        <div ng-include src="'templates/left-menu.html'"></div>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: I tried your code. Thanks a lot. But it doesnt work for me, and I feel I have wrongly placed my codes.

Comment: Okay @anithaprasad I guess you can accept answer then.

Comment: Sorry @amarmishra, I am not able to do so. Can you pls let me know how should I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-side-menus>
     <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive header-color">
        <!-- Header title and back button codes-->
      </ion-nav-bar>

      <ion-nav-view animation="slide-ios" class="dashboard_pane">
        <!-- Main body content will go here -->

        <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
                <button menu-toggle = "left" class = "button button-icon icon ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleSideMenu()"></button>
                <h1 class="title">DASHBOARD</h1>
                <button class="button" ng-click="getSyncData()" style='background-image:url(../img/sync.png);width:35px;height:35px;background-size:cover'></button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content padding="true" >
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-60 col-offset-60" style='background-image:url(../img/schbg1.png);width:15px;height:160px;background-size: 100% 100%;'><img ng-src='../img/about.png' ng-click="AboutUs()"/></div>
                        <div class="col col-60 col-offset-60" style='background-image:url(../img/schbg1.png);width:15px;height:160px;background-size:100% 100%'><img ng-src='../img/contact.png' ng-click="ContactUs()" /></div>
                    </div>
        </ion-content>
     </ion-nav-view>

    </ion-side-menu-content> 

    <ion-side-menu side="left" enable-menu-with-back-views="false" width="290">
      <ion-content has-header="false">

        <!-- Left menu code will go here-->
        <!-- You can also create a separate html file for left menu and include like this -->
        <!--<div ng-include src="'menu.html'"></div> -->
        **<ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/search">
          Search
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/browse">
          Browse
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
          Playlists
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>**


      </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```